# Reaching iCloud thumbnail dictionary

Tags: objective-c, macos, icloud, quicklook

I am trying to update thumbnail image for file in iCloud drive.

I have already read old answers about this, people are suggesting to use NSFileCoordinator and etc. but essentially you have to access thumbnail dictionary with NSURLThumbnailDictionaryKey with this method:

```
- (BOOL)getResourceValue:(out id _Nullable * _Nonnull)value forKey:(NSURLResourceKey)key error:(out NSError ** _Nullable)error
```

and then change value for NSThumbnail1024x1024SizeKey.
But apple documentation says:

**This method applies only to URLs that represent file system resources.**

Is there a way to access iCloud drive files via URL and update the thumbnail?

Answer (score 0):

Following link from Apple documentation provides clear solution for iOS (scroll down till *iCloud Document Thumbnails*): [Apple documentation link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl?language=objc) also there is steps for macOS using Quick Look.

Has anyone done something similar? the Quick Look documentation is so unclear with this simple step to update thumbnail in iCloud.